# Magento2: Is it possible to get a reference to containers and programmatically add blocks to them?

Tags: magento2, layout, containers

```
 $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
        ->setTemplate('MyModule_ProductTile::widget\test.phtml');


 $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')` returns false, I found a suggestion to use `$this->loadLayout()` but I get an invalid error function

Comment: have you put that code in controller?

Comment: It is in the constructor of a widget  
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Json $serializer,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $block = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setTemplate('MyModule_ProductTile::widget\test.phtml');
      //  var_dump( $this->getLayout());

     $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set something like below code:

protected $_resultPageFactory;

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory

) {
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);

}

public function execute()
{

    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__(' heading '));

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Companyname\Module\Block\blockname')
            ->setTemplate('MyModule_ProductTile::widget\test.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
}
}
```